# Gmail Send Quota, When Sending Using Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, email, gmail

Gmail imposes a daily 500 recipient quota for sending emails. If you send through their POP/IMAP interface that quota is only 100 recipients per day.

What is the sending quota for sending an email on a gmail account using the google app engine? Would it follow the POP/IMAP limit or the standard gmail limit?

Here is all the official gmail quota information I found:
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839

Comment: POP and IMAP are for reading emails, not sending them.  Did you mean SMTP?

Comment: actually, no. I meant POP/IMAP. See http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839

Comment: the "pop/imap clients" referred to in that link use SMTP (Send Mail Transfer Protocol) to send the actual mail.  You could just as well be sending the mail through gmail's SMTP using a python script.  Their link is conflating things for simplicity I think.  of course, none of this matters if what you are really trying to do is use app engine's mail api :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on how you decide to send the email.

- Are you using the built in App Engine mailing API? If so you, can send lots and lots of emails (see amir's answer).
- Are you sending your mail through Gmail's SMTP server? ( I assume you meant SMTP when you said POP, as POP is only for reading email) If so, the limit is 100, as you state.
- Is your app connecting to gmail through http and pretending to be a human using the normal interface?  Then the 500 limit would apply.

Comment: Are you saying that the gmail quota does not apply when you use the app engine's mailing api?

Comment: @speedplane Correct. Just because the from or reply-to address is `@gmail.com` doesn't mean gmail is involved.

Comment: Oops!  Now I see where the confusion was.  Hopefully it makes more sense to you now.

Answer (score 3):

When using app engine api to send emails (and you have billing enabled), you can send 4900 emails/minute.  See the quotas on this page:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Mail

Comment: That's not the limit I'm referring to. There is a app engine limit and a gmail limit. I know app engine's limit is 5000, but gmail's limit is much lower.

Comment: My guess is that the quota you are talking about is much higher when sent through the api, and doesn't adhere to a simple 100/500 cap.  People use this api to send tons of emails, so it doesn't make sense to have such a low cap.  I wouldn't surprise me if they don't have a cap, but integrate with the spam signals from gmail, to block/cap emails sent.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Google has [changed the quota for email](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail) recently. The limit has gone down to 100 emails per day, with no option to buy more.
Google advises to use [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid) to send more email.
If anyone could post Java code to use sendgrid, that would be helpful, as Google's documentation is lacking, as usual.
Edit: There is [documentation for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sendgrid). I have not tried this yet.

Comment: I started using postmarkapp.com. It's similar to Sendgrid, except it saves a copy of your outgoing mail for 45 days. This can be helpful if you're sending emails with dynamic content, and you want to confirm what you're sending looks legit.

Comment: The GAE mail quotas are further changed to 10 per day only (Recipients Emailed ), thus quite high time to move on to some-thing else.