# Maximum sending rate and daily quota for Gmail+Google Apps Script?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I wrote a small Google Apps Script to send out personalized e-mails (conference invitations) individually to recipients (i.e. one recipient per e-mail). As a workaround to the issue of e-mails sent using `GmailApp.sendEmail` not showing up in the Sent Mail folder, I have one script send the e-mails to itself (i.e. the sender and recipient are the same), then another script to forward those to the appropriate recipients. There are only about 100 (maybe less) verified recipients, but I'm concerned that sending out the e-mails as fast as the script executes might get them flagged as spam due to the rate at which they are being sent. My questions are the following:

1. If a Google Apps Script accesses a Gmail account to send and forward e-mails using `GmailApp`, does it incur a sending rate limit (e.g. in e-mails/second, kB/second, etc.)?
2. Which quota applies to said script? Is it Gmail's 500/day or Google Apps' 100/day?

P.S. I found [this discussion about quotas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882969/gmail-send-quota-when-sending-using-google-app-engine), but I'm not sure if my case falls under either of the scenarios described therein.

Answer (score 3):

1. There are no such limits. There is a limit on the body size per email - 20KB
2. It's 500 emails/day for Gmail users and free Google Apps users. Please note though that CCing and BCCing are all counted against your quota. So if you send one email and CC it to 500 hundred people you would have used up all your quota for that day. Also, there are additional quotas when sending emails within a domain.

Answer (score 3):

Also, the method `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` will tell you how many more emails you can send that day.

Answer (score 0):

All the quotas are described here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

How are e-mails sent using GmailApp.sendEmail not showing up in the Sent Mail folder?